# Defining Web API routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api

I'm exposing functionality through a web API, and the urls I want to expose are for example:

- /api/organizations (returns list of organizations (GET))
- /api/organizations?$top=2 (returns list of organizations filtered by oData (GET))
- /api/organizations/2 (returns details of organization with id 2 (GET))
- /api/organizations/addinstitution (adds a new institution to an organization (POST))
- /api/organizations/removeinstitution (removes an institution (POST))

In order to do that, I had to change the routing in **WebApiConfig** class like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d*" }
        );

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SpecificActionsRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This seems to work, but I was wondering if this is the most optimal way of defining the routes. Do I need two routes? Is there maybe a better way?

EDIT: to be complete, I have to say I also use attribute routing like:

```
[GET("organizations")]
public IQueryable<OrganizationSummaryViewModel> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Organization> oDataQuery)
{
}

[GET("organizations/{id}")]
public OrganizationDetailsViewModel Get(int id)
{
}

[POST("organizations/addinstitutiontoorganization")]
public AddInstitutionToOrganizationCommandResult AddInstitutionToOrganization(AddInstitutionToOrganizationCommand command)
{
}

[POST("organizations/anotheroperation")]
public AnotherOPerationCommandResult AnotherOperation(AnotherOperationCommand command)
{
}
```

EDIT 2: I ended up with removing attribute routes, and just kept the two templated routes in WebApiConfig.

Comment: Doesn't your first route need a default for `action`?

Comment: The first route maps automatically to Get or Get(int id). I think it's because it's an ApiController?

Comment: There is also an alternative way to define routes and it's called Attribute Routing. I needed it when I had to define 3 levels. Take a look at this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @L-Three Oh ok, I assumed it was working since you didn't say anything about an error but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @alfoks, yes I also use attribute routing, but still it seems you have to define the correct routes in WebApiConfig, because otherwise it seems it cannot map the attribute routes correctly. Is this correct?

Comment: @L-Three I think that you can just use Attribute routing. In my config I have only the default routing and using attributes for all the other paths.

Comment: @alfoks: I edited my question and added the attribute routing. If I don't add the extra route, I get an error on executing addinstitutiontoorganization and anotheroperation, because it tries to map addinstitutiontoorganization and anotheroperation to id..

Comment: @L-Three I don't know if this the same case as mine, but apart from the routing attribute I also have to mark each function with a method attribute i.e [HttpGet], [HttpPost], etc. If I just use [GET(...)], [POST(...)] it doesn't work and have similar problems to your's. Also I don't see anywhere in your path the "api" part. I think it should be like [GET("api/organizations")], except if you don't want it and you don't have any MVC routes that would conflict without it. In any case I'm still in the beginning with routing so my advises might not be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is the best way to define the routes for the URLs you plan on handling.  The two routes cannot be consolidated because your first route that handles two-segment URLs is assigning the second segment to `id`, whereas your second route for handling three-segment URLs assigns the second segment to `action`.  It is necessary to have two different routes because you are assigning the values differently based on whether there are two or three segments to the URL.